# How can I query a database based on a user text input?

Tags: php, html

So I am creating a Lorem Ipsum generator and I am stuck.

I have created a table called "wutangsoldiers", which contains the id of the user, their name, and each row has a different lyric. So far I have this:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
global $wpdb;
$lyrics = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wutangsoliders` WHERE `name` = '$id' ");
```

Inside of the generated text div, I have

```
<?php foreach ($lyrics as $lyrics) {
?>
<p><?php echo $lyrics->text;?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

How would I limit the number of "lyrics" shown based what the user inputs in `<input type="submit" id="blaow" name="blaow">`

Comment: `foreach ($lyrics as $lyrics)` ? seriously ?

Comment: @shatheesh It's strange, but perfectly valid. If `$lyrics` array isn't used again it won't matter.

Comment: How do you want to limit and why.. Do you want pagination?

Comment: @MarkM yeah I do agree that, but it appeared weird

Comment: Oops, I'm kind of new to PHP and was doing separate queries for each rapper. So, I havd foreach $lyrics as $rzalyrics, guess I don't need that anymore.

Comment: so, @Astrokotch have you tried your query in PHPMyadmin or console or some mysql utility and executed ? Checked for any error in query ?

Comment: Yeah, it's all good. It currently shows all the lyrics associated to that rapper under his name.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID of the user based on a (I assume a text Input) I also assume that you are using HTTP POST METHOD  ($_POST)

This is the User Value

```
<form>

<input type="text" value="1" name="user_value">

<input type="submit" id="blaow" name="blaow">
</form>
```

This is how to get the value

```
if(isset($_POST['blaow']){ // if the input has been pressed

   $idUser = $_POST['user_value']; // the value sent from the HTML above

   $lyrics = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wutangsoliders` WHERE `name` = '$idUser' ");

foreach ($lyrics as $lyrics) {

  print "<p>".$lyrics->text."</p>";

}

}
```

Comment: So, that doesn't work. I need to limit it by a number that the user inputs. The user doesn't input the name of the rapper. Before the input, it says "I want to generate <input> number of paragraphs. The "WHERE name=$id" gets the correct rapped that the paragraphs are generated from. Let me know if I'm explaining it correctly or not.

Comment: Then just add limit by 0,$user on your SQL at the end of the SQL sentence

Answer (score 0):

Just get the user input limit that

`$userinput = $_GET['lyrics_limit'];`

Then put it in sql query

`$lyrics = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM`wutangsoliders`WHERE`name`= '$id' limit '$userinput' " );`

Then you will get only according to the input by user.